# MongoDB query with special characters in key

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, special-characters

In my case, I have keys in my MongoDB database that contain a dot in their name (see attached screenshot). I have read that it is possible to store data in MongoDB this way, but the driver prevents queries with dots in the key. Anyway, in my MongoDB database, keys do contain dots and I have to work with them.

I have now tried to encode the dots in the query (. to \u002e) but it did not seem to work. Then I had the idea to work with regex to replace the dots in the query with any character but regex seems to only work for the value and not for the key.

Does anyone have a creative idea how I can get around this problem? For example, I want to have all the CVE numbers for 'cve_results.BusyBox 1.12.1'.

**Update #1:**
The structure of cve_results is as follows:

```
"cve_results" : {
            "BusyBox 1.12.1" : {
                "CVE-2018-1000500" : {
                    "score2" : "6.8",
                    "score3" : "8.1",
                    "cpe_version" : "N/A"
                },
                "CVE-2018-1000517" : {
                    "score2" : "7.5",
                    "score3" : "9.8",
                    "cpe_version" : "N/A"
                }
            }}
```

[image: MongoDB data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following workaround I was able to directly access documents by their keys, even though they have a dot in their key:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
{$match: {mymapfield: {$type: "object" }}}, //filter objects with right field type
{$project: {mymapfield: { $objectToArray: "$mymapfield" }}}, //"unwind" map to array of {k: key, v: value} objects
{$match: {mymapfield: {k: "my.key.with.dot", v: "myvalue"}}} //query
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it could be worth inserting documents using `\u002e` instead of the dot, that way you can query them while retaining the ASCII values of the `.` for any client rendering.

However, It appears there's a work around to query them like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate({ 
    $match: {
        "BusyBox 1.12.1" : "<value>"
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, cve_results is not a field. I have updated the question and added the structure of cve_results.

Comment: @Lisa So cve_results is the collection name right? I have changed my code, please try that?

Comment: In fact, the upper structure is only a snippet of a document. The full path is processed_analysis.cve_lookup.cve_results and the collection is named file_objects.
In your solution, a specific value is passed with the query (e.g. 'CVE-2011-2716'). But I would like to query all CVE numbers of a requested software without giving a specific value in the query.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use [$eq operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) to query fields with dots in names.